# SWIG generated code leaks memory when returning early

Tags: java, swig

Given the following script:

```
%typemap(in,noblock=1) int * {
    $1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if($1 == NULL) {
        return $null;
    }
}
%typemap(freearg,noblock=1) int * {
    free($1);
}


void afunc(int *varA, int *varB);
```

For Java, SWIG generates:

```
SWIGEXPORT void JNICALL Java_testmoduleJNI_afunc(JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, jlong jarg1, jlong jarg2) {
  int *arg1 = (int *) 0 ;
  int *arg2 = (int *) 0 ;
  
  (void)jenv;
  (void)jcls;
  arg1 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  if(arg1 == NULL) {
    return ;
  }
  arg2 = malloc(sizeof(int));
  if(arg2 == NULL) {
    return ;
  }
  afunc(arg1,arg2);
  free(arg1);
  free(arg2);
}
```

If `arg2` fails to allocate successfully, this would leak the memory allocated for `arg1`. Python and other languages have SWIG_fail, but this doesn't exist for Java. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Are you targeting C++? Or happy with gcc extensions?

Comment: C++ (to avoid other SWIG problems)